# What is wrong with the code formatting in this answer?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

It took me a while, but in the end I found a solution. 
I created a script with the following content that I place within the graphviz directory. `GVTARGET` is a directory within my development directory that I use from Xcode. The script will create all the necessary .a files and will copy the C-versions together with the .h files into the target directory. For some odd reason, the .h doesn't work completely, it might not be needed. Assuming the file is called gv.sh then you need to call it from `GVROOT` with `./gv.sh`

```
INSTALLER_ROOT="/Users/wizardofkneup"
GVROOT="${INSTALLER_ROOT}/graphviz"   
GVTARGET="${INSTALLER_ROOT}/Documents/xcode/VisualThinkingWorkspace/graphviz"
PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR="/usr/bin"

./configure \
  --disable-dependency-tracking \
  --enable-shared=no \
  --enable-static=yes \
  --enable-ltdl=no \
  --enable-swig=no \
  --enable-tcl=no \
  -srcdir=/Users/wizardofkneup/graphviz \
  --with-codegens=no \
  --with-cgraph=yes \
  --with-expat=no \
  --with-fontconfig=no \
  --with-freetype2=no \
  --with-ipsepcola=yes \
  --with-libgd=no \
  --with-xdot=yes \
 --with-quartz=yes \
  --with-visio=yes \
   --with-x=no \
   CC="${PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR}/clang" \
   CPP="${PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR}/clang -E" \
   CXX="${PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR}/clang++" \
   OBJC="${PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR}/clang" \
   LD="${PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR}/ld" 

make

rm -rf ${GVTARGET}
mkdir -p ${GVTARGET}
find . -type f -name '*_C.a' -exec cp -i {} ${GVTARGET} \;
find . -type f -name '*.h' -exec cp {} -i ${GVTARGET} \;
```

A few further comments:

- Use Homebrew to get the sources for graphviz. `brew install --build-from-source graphviz`
- copy & unzip downloaded sources from `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew` into `GRVIZ` directory
- Define environment variable `GRVIZ`, either for terminal or in Xcode, pointing at dev directory `GVROOT`. 
  Set header path and swift import path to `${GRVIZ}/**`
- In order to have c++ standard libraries linked (needed for plugins) you need to have a empty .mm file (following walter's idea: [Compile errors with C++ static library include in Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106426/compile-errors-with-c-static-library-include-in-swift-project))
- Include all _C.a files -> we want the C interface to avoid name mangling.
- Create Builtins.c needs to be a c-file in order to avoid name mangling issues. Set this in file inspector [image]
- For yet unknown reasons do I need both: the `GRVIZ` and `GVTARGET`
  directories. Copying the c-header files alone doesn't seem to be enough
- Loading the libraries:
  [Unable to use dot layout (graphviz as a library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602127/unable-to-use-dot-layout-graphviz-as-a-library)

My builtins.c file:

```
#include "builtins.h"

extern gvplugin_library_t gvplugin_dot_layout_LTX_library;
extern gvplugin_library_t gvplugin_neato_layout_LTX_library;
extern gvplugin_library_t gvplugin_core_LTX_library;
extern gvplugin_library_t gvplugin_quartz_LTX_library;
extern gvplugin_library_t gvplugin_visio_LTX_library;

void loadGraphvizLibraries(GVC_t *gvc) {
    gvAddLibrary(gvc, &gvplugin_dot_layout_LTX_library);
    gvAddLibrary(gvc, &gvplugin_neato_layout_LTX_library);
    gvAddLibrary(gvc, &gvplugin_core_LTX_library);
    gvAddLibrary(gvc, &gvplugin_quartz_LTX_library);
    gvAddLibrary(gvc, &gvplugin_visio_LTX_library);
}
```

My builtins.h file:

```
#ifndef builtins_h
#define builtins_h

#include "/Users/klauskneupner/graphviz/lib/gvc/gvplugin.h" //
#include "gvc.h"

extern lt_symlist_t lt_preloaded_symbols[];
void loadGraphvizLibraries(GVC_t *gvc);

#endif /* builtins_h */
```

the app's Bridging-header.h

```
#include <gvc.h>
#import "builtins.h"
```

And the configuration in Xcode. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

I needed later on this one: not sure whether that was graphviz related. 
[image]

I hope this helps. Good luck. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: On what site? What do you expect the code formatting to be? Why did you post that whole thing here **instead of linking to the actual post**?

Comment: I try to post this on stack overflow, but I cannot. It doesn't let me due to code formatting issues.

Answer (score 3):

So, I searched through your answers on Stack Overflow and found this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056337/1583

I am assuming you are asking why there is no syntax highlighting on the code bit there.

The reason is that the question is tagged with `graphviz` and `appstore-sandbox`, neither of which has been set with a default code highlighter - so none is being used for the answers (since it isn't possible to know which language is being used).

You can always directly add [highlighting hints](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) yourself.

I have added those to the code sections on that answer:

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
```

Comment: you found the right question in the stackoverflow area. I would like to add more details to my answer, but I cannot. Pretty annoying when you spend quite some time and your editor doesn't let you save.

Comment: I assume your answer goes in the right direction, but still no luck for me. I even delete the tags, hoping to add them later. Nothing.

Comment: I don't really know what more to say - I've gone in to fix the issue you seem to complain about (not that you confirmed that was the case), you can see the edits to see what I've done. I added the changes you did as well - I didn't get a single error message.

Comment: oh! Well done. I somehow didn't realise. I would like to know why it worked for you, but ultimately, you are right. Thanks a lot Oded. Sorry for confusion.  And thanks